# prepareForSegue elements in Array in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I have two viewcontrller vc1 and vc2. In vc1 it is tableview parsed with json and it displays some names.

```
vc1:

var names: [String] = [] // Displays name (Ana, Mike, John ....)

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TVC

cell.lable.text = name[indexPath.row]

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let someName: vc2 =  segue.destinationViewController as! vc2
        someName.nameFromVC1 = //need code here

    }


vc2:

var nameFromVC1: String!
```

my goal is when table displays names, and I click some name say "Ana", I want "Ana"  to be sent to vc2 and put in var nameFromVC1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like this in vc 1:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // Prepare the destination view controller with the selected name
    (segue.destinationViewController as? NameDetailViewController)?
        .prepareForName(
            names[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row]
        )
}
```

And this in your destination view controller:

```
func prepareForName(name: String) {
    self.name = name
}
```

Comment: tnx I did only names[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row] and it works

Comment: No problem  have fun