# Linking tableview cell information to a view controller

Tags: swift

I'm pretty new to Swift. I wish to reflect tableview cell data (title and description of a post) in a new view controller. Here's the code I put in the first view controller (which contains the tableview cell).

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PostCell!

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]

    valuetoPass = post.title
    valuetoPass_desc = post.postDescription

    performSegueWithIdentifier("seguetoVC", sender: self)

}
```

And this one...

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "seguetoVC" {


        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UpdateVC


        viewController.toPassTitle = valuetoPass
        viewController.toPassDesc = valuetoPass_desc
    }

}
```

Here's a part of UpdateVC..Added the variables, toPassTitle and toPassDesc...And these are the lines I added to viewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.postTxt.delegate = self
    self.descTxt.delegate = self
    descTxt.text = toPassTitle
    postTxt.text = toPassDesc
}
```

Just wondering what I'm doing wrong-- viewController.toPassTitle and viewController.toPassDesc keep on returning a null value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you check their values? Can you also show destination vc to show how you use the properties?

Comment: Used the console to print the values. Edited my question to show the destination vc. Thanks!

Comment: are you show the code in the if statement is executed? In your storyboard, is the segue identifier equal to **seguetoVC**?

Comment: I think this could be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/a/35832726/5594781

Comment: Yes, the segue identifier is equal to **seguetoVC**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `sender` parameter to be whatever type you want, there's no reason for it to be `self`, i.e. the originating view controller if that's not what you need. In fact, there should never be a need to pass the originating view controller as the `sender`, because you can get it from `segue.sourceViewController` in `prepareForSegue`.

In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:) for `prepareForSegue`, Apple suggests:

> Because segues can be triggered from multiple sources, you can use the information in the segue and sender parameters to disambiguate between different logical paths in your app. For example, if the segue originated from a table view, the sender parameter would identify the table view cell that the user tapped. You could then use that information to set the data on the destination view controller.

Which sounds like exactly the situation you're in. Since you've already figured out the model object for your cell, we can pass that rather than the cell. So, you could call `performSegueWithIdentifier("seguetoVC", sender: post)`, and then change up your `prepareForSegue` implementation to use the details from the post directly, e.g.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "seguetoVC" {
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UpdateVC
        if let post = sender as ? Post {
            viewController.toPassTitle = post.title
            viewController.toPassDesc = post.postDescription
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need to call `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PostCell!` anywhere, and it could be fairly expensive, so don't do it if you don't use it. Your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method might look more like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("seguetoVC", sender: post)
}
```

There's also a bunch more you could do to make it safer, so have a look at unwrapping optionals using constructs such as `if let` and `guard let`, which can also help you avoid force casting (`!`), and potentially crashing your app. I've done that in unwrapping `sender` to `post`, so you can see an example there.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to declare `indexPath` again. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` already has `indexPath`. Update your codes in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]

    valuetoPass = post.title
    valuetoPass_desc = post.postDescription

    performSegueWithIdentifier("seguetoVC", sender: self)

}
```

On top of that, ensure that in your storyboard, you need to name your segue identifier with `seguetoVC` also.